# Ways to get your managedObjectContext to the initial viewController OS X

Tags: macos, swift, core-data, dependency-injection, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is how I'm currently doing it but I'm wondering if this is how Apple suggests. I've read some debates about that.

```
let appDelegate : AppDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
if let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
    // do stuff here
}
```

So that's just to get it from the `AppDelegate` to the first `viewController`. From there I'm guessing that using `segues` is the way to go to pass around the `managedObjectContext`?

Using the above code is pretty annoying because I'm typing that into every method in the `viewController` that needs the `MOC`. It's even more annoying when I have a function with a `return` statement and all my code that uses the `MOC` is inside the body of the `if statement` since that creates errors stating that there is/may not be a `return`. Is there a better way to do that, like make it more global?

**EDIT:**

My ViewController.swift file has this header:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
```

and contains a Table View

My AppDelegate.swift file has:

```
import Cocoa
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple sample code stores and creates the Core Data stack in the app delegate, but that doesn't mean it's right. In fact, it's entirely wrong. The app delegate shouldn't own the data store. Apple does it, and most people follow along, because it's convenient. You should really have a custom class which owns and creates the Core Data stack.

This custom class needs to be instantiated somewhere, that could be in the app delegate and then passed to your root view controller, or it could be in the root view controller itself. This custom class could also be a singleton (because you don't want multiple instances of it).

Each view controller should have a public property for the MOC which is set by its creator (part of the segue code). In this way each controller isn't going and getting the MOC, the MOC dependency is being injected. This helps keep the relationships clean and aids in unit testing. You also don't need the `let` to check you got the MOC back - if it isn't there it's a development issue (and if it couldn't be created you should never have created / pushed the view controller...).

Comment: That's good information. Thank you. So all these custom classes that I see people make that I can add to my project have the right idea? So I can just use one of them? Also, you stated that the MOC could be instantiated in the app delegate and then passed to the root view controller. How do I do that since there is no segue?

Comment: The app delegate has a property holding the window and the window has a property for the root view controller...

Comment: I understand the idea your saying but I'm unable to code that. If you have time helping me with the code would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to do it using Swift which really makes finding examples difficult.

Comment: I don't know what your root view controller is, or the property it has. Give it a try and create a new question, showing what you have, if it doesn't work.

Comment: I added some code in the question. Not sure if it helps or not but other than showing all the Core Data stuff there isn't much to it.

Comment: But are you using a navigation controller? What is initial in the storyboard? Have you tried adding an instance variable to your controller?